# if and else if statements in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

What is the difference between this:

`s = 0;
if (x > 0) s++;
if (y > 0) s++;`

and this:

`s = 0;
if (x > 0) s++;
else if (y > 0) s++;`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be easily found in any introductory programming book, as well as all over Google.

Comment: @chris:  Have some mercy on a beginner.  Part of being a beginner is not even knowing how to ask your question to Google as you haven't yet learned the terminology to ask it.  And I'll bet that the OP is already staring at an introductory programming book, but not quite getting it.

Comment: Please read MISRA Coding Guidelines, as they state that every "if, else-if" ladder needs a terminating else statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Sorry to say, but that makes little sense to me. Adding an empty `else {}` just because?

Comment: @chris: You have to restructure the `if` so that the `else-if` doesn't require an empty else clause.

Answer (score 9):

When you write `else if` instead of `if`, program will not check the `else if` statement if `x > 0`, but when you write two `if` statements program will check both conditions, no matter if `x > 0` or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case the both conditions are checked because there are two different if statements.

In the second case the second condition is checked only if the first condition is evaluated to false.

Answer (score 1):

Say x is 10 and y is 10. At the end of the first set of statements, s will be equal to 2. At the end of the second set of statements, s will be equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The second example

```
s = 0;
if (x > 0) s++;
else if (y > 0) s++;`
```

will check for the `y` value only if `x > 0` is false. The first example will execute the check regardless of `x`'s value.